# javascripts/lib/angular.min.js after deploying to heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku

I get this error after I deployed my app on Heroku, I have included my project structure? it clearly shows that I have included the files but I get an empty page with the shown error. Why?

[image: The error I get]
[image: my project structure]

on my app.js

```
app.use('/api',routesApi);
    app.use(function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'app_client', 'index.html'));
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that once deployed, `public` folder is not anymore the root of your webapp